# Indexing long text fields failing using arcpy AddIndex?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, attribute-index

Arcpy AddIndex_management won't index long text fields, is there a workaround?

I tried:

```
arcpy.AddIndex_management(r'C:\workspace\foo.dbf', "Text")
```

and got the error:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 5993, in AddIndex     
  raise e ExecuteError: 
  ERROR 999999: Error executing function. 
  Attribute indexes cannot be created for fields with a length that is greater than 80. 
Failed to execute (AddIndex).
```

I have also tried this with shapefiles as well as dbf's with the same error.  I need to index a text field in order to perform a JoinField() more quickly with arcpy.

Is there a work around to do this that doesn't involve shortening text fields?

I haven't seen a reason not to index fields longer than 80 characters; especially since the text fields I'm indexing have been calculated and are therefore not very prone to typos. For example, if you had a series of field of species names and you wanted to join that to a table containing descriptions of those species, you would be joining on a potentially long text string.

Comment: The problem here appears to be the *length* of the text field, rather than the fact that it's a text field.  Have you tried it on fields shorter than 80 characters?  Performing a join on a value longer than 80 characters seems unusual and risky (for typos) to me.

Comment: I have now and it does work.  I haven't seen a reason not to index fields longer than 80 characters; especially since the text fields I'm indexing have been calculated and are therefore not very prone to typos.  
For example, if you had a series of field of species names and you wanted to join that to a table containing descriptions of those species, you would be joining on a potentially long text string.

Comment: Could you create a new coded value field for those values in each table, and index and join on those?

Comment: I suppose I could.  Ok, next question is if I am exporting an excel file with a text field to a dbf, how do I get the length of that field to not be the standard 256?  Should I ask that as another question?

Comment: Yes ask as a separate question

Comment: Although I would ask why you're creating/using DBF files?  Import everything into a file geodatabase and index/join the geodatabase tables or feature class.  Alternatively use `in_memory` datasets.  You can write everything back to table/excel etc. at the end of the arcpy processing

Comment: Mostly because a gdb seems like overkill for a single table and because I'm not very handy with in_memory datasets.  A second reason is because this is part of a long process, and having a dbf in the middle that I can go back to in case of errors down the line is helpful.

Comment: You say that a gdb is overkill, but that this is part of a long process.  I think DBF will be your bottleneck/pain point with all it's peculiarities.

Comment: I should have been more clear; the overall process is long, not the part using the dbf.  The process uses temp files (including this dbf) because the inputs are a CAD file and an excel file, and the output is a configured gdb that my boss won't let me add another table to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you CAN edit the length of text fields the answer is as follows:

```
arcpy.AddField(r'C:\workspace\foo.dbf', "shortText", "#", "#", 75, "#", "#", "#", "#")
with arcpy.da.updateCursor(r'C:\workspace\foo.dbf', ["Text", "shortText"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0]
        cursor.updateCursor(row)
arcpy.AddIndex_management(r'C:\workspace\foo.dbf', "shortText")
```

and then perform your join on "shortText"